# ¿Existe una manera de hacer una cadena con una subcadena grabada en el localStorage?

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber si es posible hacer una cadena que contenga otra que previamente ya se ha guardado en el localStorage ya que por ejemplo primero grabo la cadena

```
function claveS(e) {
   if(!e) e = window.event;
   let a = e.target.textContent;
   let cl = a.replaceAll(" ","_");
   let clave = cl+"/info.json";
   localStorage.setItem("clave", claveS);
}
```

y en determinada función quisiera implementar algo similar a lo del código que se encuentra más abajo ya que mi idea sería proporcionarle de un dirección completa de donde se encuentra el archivo en caso de ser necesario

```
function clave(e) {
   if(!e) e = window.event;
   let a = e.target.textContent;
   let cl = a.replaceAll(" ","_");
   let clave = localStorage.getItem("claveS")+cl+"/info.json";
   localStorage.setItem("clave", clave);
}
```

que es recomendable si por lo que se indica en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage el localStorage es solo de lectura, ya que por razones del Storage tampoco pude obtener la "clave" para después realizar un substring.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Quieres hacer: "cadena \"subcadena\" "?

Comment: Que tal si haces una cadena que contenga un JSON : `"{ \"files\":{\"name\":\"name.txt\",\"url\":\"...\"} } "; ` y la ingresas por localStorage. Despues la recuperas usando la clase JSON que ofrese el navegador.